# Reformatting list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to convert `[a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c]` > and so on, to `[a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c]` > and so on, in python?

Note, there can be also more than three same letters

Comment: What do you mean an so on? Could you be more specific about the input/ output?

Comment: so you're talking about characters in particular?

Comment: All different letters appear the same amount of times? Please be specific

Comment: And so on means there also can be rest of the alfabetical letters but in sorted way like d,d,d,e,e,e,f,f,f and so on

Comment: "and so on" is not a description, read [ask] and show your own attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `zip` and [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) `chain`, `groupby`:

```
l = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*(list(x) for _, x in groupby(l)))))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

As the problem is poorly described, I will make some assumptions. I will assume that each letter present in the input is present as many times as the others. Thus, the idea to create the output is to identify which unique letters are present in the input, and how many times. Moreover, I will assume that the input and output are list of strings. With that in mind, the following procedure works:

```
list_input = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
list_unique_elements = list(set(list_input))
list_count = list_input.count(list_unique_elements[0])
list_output = list_unique_elements*list_count
```

Output:

```
Out: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
lst = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']

d = {}
for e in lst:
    if e in d:
        d[e].append((len(d[e]), e))
    else:
        d[e] = [(0, e)]

result = sorted(value for values in d.values() for value in values)
result = [e[1] for e in result]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

**Note**: This solution is general in the sense that it does not needs the characters to be sorted, not to appear the same amount of times each.